# How to remove category without sub category

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

How to remove category without sub category ?

Category Model :

```
   public class Category 
    {
        public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual int? ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

datas :

```
Id          ParentId    Name
1           null        Hot
2           1           Soup
3           1           Coffee
4           3           Decaf Coffee
5           null        Cold
6           5           Iced Tea
```

i need to remove Category with `Id=1` but The following error occurs :

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE
>   constraint "FK_dbo.Categories_dbo.Categories_ParentId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "ProjectDatabase", table "dbo.Categories", column
>   'ParentId'.
>       The statement has been terminated.

my delete code :

```
  public void Delete(int categoryId)
        {
            var category = _categories.First(d => d.Id == categoryId);
            _categories.Remove(category);
        }
```

CategoryConfig :

```
 public class CategoryConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
    {
        public CategoryConfig()
        {
            ToTable("Categories");
            HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete),  *if a foreign key on the dependent entity is `nullable`, Code First does not set cascade delete on the relationship (which you are doing explicitly), and when the principal is deleted the foreign key will be set to `null`.*

I don't know why is not doing that in your case, probably is because you are working with an unidirectional relationship and you don't have the collection of children in your parent Category, so EF couldn't set the FK properties to `null` in the subcategories, but you can try the following:

```
var category = _categories.First(d => d.Id == categoryId);
var children=_categories.Where(d=>d.ParentId==categoryId);
foreach(var c in children)
   c.ParentId=null;
_categories.Remove(category);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the category with `Id=1` because there are subcategories referenced to it (*Soup* and *Coffee*). In your delete method you'll have to either change the `ParentId` of these items first to another existing element (or *null*) or delete these items before deleting the category with `Id=1`.